# preventing negative values from text

Tags: javascript, html

How to disable or prevent negative values from textbox?

this is the code from my js file:

```
function compare(val)
{
if(document.getElementById("num1").value==""||document.getElementById("num2").value=="")
{
alert("Click start to start the game");
}
else
{
uservalue=compute(randomnumber1,val,randomnumber2);
if(uservalue==document.getElementById("res").value)
{
    score=score+100;
    document.getElementById("rimg").src="images/correct.png";
    document.getElementById("txt2").value=score;
}
else if(uservalue!=document.getElementById("res").value)
{
    score=score-100;
    document.getElementById("rimg").src="images/wrong.png";
    document.getElementById("txt2").value=score;

}
else
document.getElementById("rimg").src="images/wrong.png";
generate();
    }
    }
```

textbox in html file:

```
<input id="txt2" readonly="true" type="text" value="0" name="score">
```

in `score=score-100;` I keep on getting negative values. Can anyone help me out?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is 'score' value before subtracting 100 from it? Maybe that is making your score value negative.

Comment: Where does `score` come from in the first place?

Comment: BTW, there's no way to get to the `else` clause in your `if`. Either `uservalue` equals `res.value` or it doesn't, there's no third possibility.

Answer (score 1):

After you subtract 100 from `score`, check to see if it's below zero. If it is, set it to zero.

```
score -= 100;
if(score < 0) {
    score = 0;
}
```

Comment: Or: `score = Math.max(0,score-100);`